# Can there be a holomorphic function that $f(\frac 1 n ) = \frac{1}{n^2 + (-1)^n}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let's consider the problem following: I want to judge whether there can exist holomorphic function $f:\Delta(0, 1) \rightarrow \mathbb C$ such satisfies for $n \ge 2$:

$$f(\frac 1 n) = \frac{1}{n^2 + (-1)^n}$$

where $\Delta(0, 1) := \{z \in \mathbb C: |z| < 1\}$.

**My thoughts**

I wanted somehow to find counterexample with one of the properties of holomorphic functions. Firstly we know that if $f$ is holomorphic on $\Delta(0, 1)$ it has to be continuous on that set. I tried to pick sequences $(a_n) \rightarrow 0$, $|a_n| < 1$ but $f(a_n) \nrightarrow 0$ but I didn't find any satisfying example.

Another approach that I had is that we know if $f$ is holomorphic and non-constant then $f(\Delta(0, 1))$ has to be an open set (since $\Delta(0, 1)$ is an open set), but I also didn't know how to prove that $f(\Delta(0, 1))$ is not an open set.

Could I please ask you for a hand in proving this fact?

**EDIT**

As suggested in answer if we define:

$$g(z) = f(z) - \frac{z^2}{1 + z^2}$$

If $k \in \mathbb Z$, then $g(\frac{1}{2k}) = 0$ and:

$$g(\frac{1}{2k + 1}) = \frac{1}{(2k + 1)^2 - 1} - \frac{1}{(2k + 1)^2 + 1} = \frac{2}{((2k + 1)^2 - 1)((2k + 1)^2 + 1)}$$

So $g(\frac 1 n ) \rightarrow 0 \in \Delta(0, 1)$

Identity theorem says that if set

$$N(f, g) := \{z \in \Delta(0, 1): f(z) = g(z)\}$$ has limit point in $\Delta(0, 1)$ then $f \equiv g$. In our example it would suggest that $g \equiv 0$ since we found a limit point that belongs to this set. Out of this we can obtain that $f(z) = \frac{z^2}{1 + z^2}$

Answer (score 4):

Let $g(z)=f(z)-\frac {z^{2}} {1+z^{2}}$. Check that $g(\frac  1 n)=0$ for $n$ even. What does the Identity Theorem tell you?

Comment: It means that $f \equiv g$ on $\Delta(0, 1)$ right?

Comment: So what happens when you take $n$ odd?

Comment: @Lucian No, that's not what it means. Try again.

Comment: I updated my answer. Could you please have a look on it and say if now it make more sense to you?

Comment: If $f(z)$ has that form then the given equation will not hold for odd values of $n$. So you have to conclude that such a function $f$ DOES NOT EXIST. @Lucian